# Resigning when you have multiple bosses in multiple locations?

Tags: professionalism, communication, resignation

On Monday I intend to resign from my current position. I'm a consultant, and nearly always placed on site. I very occasionally have a boss on-site with me and another that always works managing the development team in the "back of house" a couple of hours away from my location. Both are considered equal partners and both were equally involved in my hiring process.

What is the professional approach when resigning here? I've thought about writing an e-mail and titling it to both of them, but it doesn't seem appropriate for this kind of situation. Would it be ok to just ask to meet the boss that comes on-site on Monday and only have the discussion with him or should I invite my other boss also (a very significant round trip for him)?

Comment: Personally I'd say mail them both. This gives them time to gauge the situation and arrange a meeting with one/both if needed. Coming out in a meeting with two managers is liable to put one manager off message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Simon suggested, I would also recommend to write an email **equally** addressed to
all parties. Given your bosses are all equal in their work area, and you don't have the situation that one of them takes more care of HR stuff, and the other more technical stuff etc.

And even if that was the case, it would be just fair to inform all of them, so nobody
would feel left out of the decision. You give them the chance to react to some extent, in what matter they may prefer (condolement for example, or best wishes).
That is a good basis for future collaboration, when you cross paths with one of them again.
You never know!

Comment: I Agree to the e-mail, but I would definitely follow-up with both of them individually, either in-person or by phone.